# j2me: Recommended way to display a considerable number of results

Tags: json, java-me, tabular

I want to ask you if you know of practical way to display data (maybe in tabular format) coming from a WebService.

I'm really new to j2me, I've just learned how to consume RESTful webservices, now I need to learn how show that data (which comes in json format) to the user.

Basically this is the code I use:

```
 protected String jsonParse(String url) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection hc = null;
        System.out.println(url);
        String Results = null;
        try {
            mProgressString.setText("Connecting...");
            hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ);
            hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");
            if (hc.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                is = hc.openInputStream();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuffer.append((char) ch);
                }
            }
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.out.println("Security Excepction: " + se);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("Null Pointer Excepction: " + npe);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception" + ioe);
        }
        try {
            hc.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in MostActivePareser Connection close:" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String jsonData = stringBuffer.toString();
        try {
            JSONArray js = new JSONArray(jsonData);            
            System.out.println(js.length());
            mProgressString.setText("Reading...");
            String Results = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsObj = js.getJSONObject(i);
                Results += "-----------------------------------\n";
                Results += jsObj.getString("Name") + " \n";
                Results += jsObj.getString("Phone") + " \n";
                Results += jsObj.getString("Address");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            System.out.println("Json Data error:" + e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("null error:" + e);
        }
         return Results;
   }
```

As you can see I only concatenating the results to then show it to the user.But surely there's gotta be better ways to that and here's where I need you help.

How would you display a typical json Array in j2me ?? How do you deal with limitations such as limited memory and small screen sizes when you have to work with a considerable number of results?

As always, any advice or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. [This is the jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonmejar.htm) I used to work with json.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871725/how-to-get-and-set-jsonobject-jsonarray-in-j2me) will definitely help you dealing with JSONArray.

To talk about memory limitation,you just try to clean up the resources/data structures that you don't need any more means about UI just keep instance of current screen alive (if possible) no need of other instances in stack.If your array contains many objects that you can't display at a one time (as can cause OOM like issues),then you can think of Pagination.

You can get better idea about Memory Optimization from this must see [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/nilanchalapanigrahy/j2me-performance-optimization-tips-tricks).

Comment: Thanks. I used the first link as a reference. In fact I don't have any problem with object or arrays in json format, they're pretty easy to work with. My question goes more for how display those objects when it comes to a considerable number of results. Pagination was another thing I had in mind, but it's just that I can't seem to find any example about that.

Comment: Suppose you have a list containing 100 elements.you can iterate first 10 elements and make a list. Show the list of 10 elements.clicking on next button ,iterate next 10 elements refill the existing list by clearing its data first.if you are willing to use basic j2me you will need Canvas.or Paid j2me-Polish and Free LWUIT will also help without ant overhead.its your choice.

Comment: Yep, I've heard of those UI frameworks.The problem is the lack of information regarding displaying large arrays in tabular format or using pagination. It's just as if they're telling you "The resources are there, see if you can make anything out of them"

Comment: you just need to use TableItem. Thats it.check this: [example](https://netbeans.org/kb/71/javame/tableitem.html) and [Wiki Page](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_show_Table_layout_data_in_a_MIDP_Form)

Comment: I found that page yesterday, and it works relatively well.I say relatively , because there's a problem with tables which have width greater than the screen. At least in my case , it does not scroll right till the end of the table.

Comment: what about pagination? Do you have any link you can share?

Comment: I did this in j2me polish.and dont have links for this as i managed myself.Although LWUIT [sample](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8ZY9NBZj0LPbTBqWEFkRTFIdWs) check that once.If the answer was useful don't forget to accept.Cheers